# How to sort os.walk(path) in alphanumeric order, with duplicates coming after the original file, using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, os.walk

In python 3 (specifically 3.10.6), how can you change the way that `os.walk(path)` sorts the files it finds? Given this list of files:

```
IMG0001.jpg
IMG0002.jpg
IMG0002(1).jpg
IMG0002(2).jpg
IMG0003.jpg
```

How would you sort it in that order, with each `(n)` duplicate file coming after the original file? Currently, `os.walk(path)` is sorting this list like this:

```
IMG0001.jpg
IMG0002(1).jpg
IMG0002(2).jpg
IMG0002.jpg
IMG0003.jpg
```

I suppose the main issue is that the default sort method is giving a higher "sort value" to the `(` (and also `-`) than it is to the `.` in the extension. If this is correct in what's happening here, how would you modify which special characters come before others?

I've tried to use `sorted(files)`, however that sorts it the same as `os.walk(path)` already sorts them. If I try `sorted(files, reverse=True),` then while the originals come before the duplicates, multiple duplicates are now sorted backward and all the originals are backward too, ie:

```
IMG0003.jpg
IMG0002.jpg
IMG0002(2).jpg
IMG0002(1).jpg
IMG0001.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String ordering is lexicographic, so you'll need a custom sort key if you want something different. It's a little trickier than expected, but something like this should work:

```
import os
import re

def key(fname):
    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
    v = 0
    if m := re.match(r"(.*)\((\d+)\)$", basename):
        basename, v = m.groups()
        v = int(v)
    return basename, ext, v
```

Now you should be able to use something like `files.sort(key=key)`.

Comment: `files = ['IMG0003.jpg', 'IMG0002(2).jpg', 'IMG0002(11).jpg', 'IMG0001.jpg', 'IMG0002.jpg', 'IMG0002(1).jpg', 'IMG0002.png']`
`print(files.sort(key=key))`
This just spits back `None` to me, not a sorted list

Comment: Nevermind, figured out that you have to use `print(sorted(files,key=key))` in my example. 

I like this one cuz it's short and simple, and supports duplicates > 9. Thanks

Comment: To support duplicates that are marked by a `-n` at the end of the base name, I changed the regex to `(.*)[\(-](\d+)\)?$`

Answer (score 1):

Using `pathlib.Path` for more awareness of filename semantics, build a tuple
with special cases as leading elements and the filename at the end.  Sort that list of tuples but keep only the last element.

```
def test():

    from pathlib import Path


    def filenamesort(inp : list[str]):
        """build a list of custom tuples from the filename list, sort it and 
        return the rightmost field, which is the filename.
        """
        
        def tupleize(v):
            """ returns a tuple of strings based on Path.stem for the filename

            special case.  split into the part before the last `(` and what comes after

            IMG0002(1).jpg => ('IMG0002', 1, 'IMG0002(2).jpg')

            normal case, return the stem and an empty value

            IMG0002.jpg  => ('IMG0002', 0, 'IMG0002.jpg')

            The last element, least significant to sort is the filename

            to be more solid foo(xxx).jpg should be ignored as xxx is not a numeric.
            
            """
            
            pa = Path(v)
            stem = pa.stem
            if stem.endswith(")"):
                lead, seq = stem.rsplit("(",maxsplit=1)
                return (lead,int(seq.rstrip(")")),v)
            else:
                # "" will sort before "1)"
                return (stem,0,v)

        li = [tupleize(v) for v in inp]


        #sort the list then return the last position in the tuple: the filename proper
        return [v[-1] for v in sorted(li)]

    
    def fmt(sin : str):
        res = [v for line in sin.splitlines() if (v:=line.strip())]
        return res

    inp = fmt("""IMG0001.jpg
IMG0002(1).jpg
IMG0002(2).jpg
IMG0002(11).jpg
IMG0002.jpg
IMG0003.jpg
""")

    exp = fmt("""IMG0001.jpg
IMG0002.jpg
IMG0002(1).jpg
IMG0002(2).jpg
IMG0002(11).jpg
IMG0003.jpg""")



    dataexp = [
        (inp,exp),
        ]

    for inp, exp in dataexp:
        for f in [filenamesort]:
            got = f(inp)
            msg = f"\n{f.__name__} for {str(inp):100.100} \nexp :{exp}:\ngot :{got}:\n"
            if exp == got:
                print(f"✅! {msg}")
            else:
                print(f"❌!  {msg}")

test()
```

##### output:

```
✅! 
filenamesort for ['IMG0001.jpg', 'IMG0002(1).jpg', 'IMG0002(2).jpg', 'IMG0002(11).jpg', 'IMG0002.jpg', 'IMG0003.jpg'] 
exp :['IMG0001.jpg', 'IMG0002.jpg', 'IMG0002(1).jpg', 'IMG0002(2).jpg', 'IMG0002(11).jpg', 'IMG0003.jpg']:
got :['IMG0001.jpg', 'IMG0002.jpg', 'IMG0002(1).jpg', 'IMG0002(2).jpg', 'IMG0002(11).jpg', 'IMG0003.jpg']:
```

I've checked that `tupleize` (the one for the tuple) can be used as a `key` parameter to `sort`.

i.e. this works as well `sorted(inp,key=tupleize)`

Wim was right, this was failing with different extension.  Fixed with adjustment below:

```
        pa = Path(v)
        stem = pa.stem
        if stem.endswith(")"):
            lead, seq = stem.rsplit("(",maxsplit=1)
            return (lead,pa.suffix, int(seq.rstrip(")")),v)
        else:
            # "" will sort before "1)"
            return (stem,pa.suffix,0,v)
```

Comment: I think the result is wrong for e.g. `IMG0001.jpg, IMG0001(1).jpg, IMG0001.png`

Comment: argh.  oh, well, that's the nice thing with the test stub I use, you can just add new data to it.  I'll check.

Comment: fixed, and confirmed to work, but not reposting the whole thing again...

Comment: You've mentioned `Pathlib` for "_awareness of filename semantics_" but I'm not sure you're really getting much help from it here.  It has to split the same string twice with the .stem and .suffix properties, vs getting both in one hit with `os.path.splitext`

Comment: @wim.  Yes, you are problably right.  I have been using Path for a while, forgot about os.path.  Easy replacement.  My key point is that it is better to rely on filename-aware functions to do the work, not just regex.  After I wrote mine I realized you used that as well, not just regex.  Btw, yours works too, impressed you got it right wo testing it.  On the plus side, I learned I can tune a key function using the list-of-tuples approach and then pass it to sort without the need for that step.  Good thing as I always struggle with key functions.